# How to return the first row after group by?

Tags: sql, group-by, firebird, firebird-3.0

My table looks like the following:

| ID | ITEMNO | LOCATIONNO | LOTNO | INCOME | OUTGO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | A-01 | 001 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | AAA | A-02 | 002 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | AAA | A-01 | 001 | 0 | 1 |

When a user sells an item, I want to show the oldest income LOTNO item (FIFO) to the user (lookup) and the user must choose the oldest LOTNO item. In short, I want to get the following result:

| ITEMNO | LOCATIONNO | LOTNO | STOCK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | A-02 | 002 | 1 |

I tried the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT ITEMNO, LOCATIONNO, LOTNO, SUM(INCOME-OUTGO) STOCK
FROM LOCATION_DETAIL 
WHERE ITEMNO = 'AAA'
GROUP BY ITEMNO, LOCATIONNO, LOTNO
ORDER BY LOTNO
```

The result of the above SQL is like the following:

| ITEMNO | LOCATIONNO | LOTNO | STOCK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | A-01 | 001 | 1 |
| AAA | A-02 | 002 | 1 |
| AAA | A-01 | 001 | -1 |

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you tell which is the oldest if you don't have any date column? What you wrote above sounds more like LIFO then FIFO.

Comment: The query you post doesn't give the output you show, it only produces two rows, not three. See https://dbfiddle.uk/zP17jn8Y

Comment: Thank you XRaySensei , LOTNO shows whichone is older for example 001 the oldest 002 new 003 the newest etc.

Answer (score 0):

After the group by, you need to filter the query using [`HAVING`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-dml.html#fblangref30-dml-select-groupby-having) to only include positive stock, [order by](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-dml.html#fblangref30-dml-select-orderby) lotno, and only return the first row using the [`FETCH` clause](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-dml.html#fblangref30-dml-select-offsetfetch).

So:

```sql
select ITEMNO, LOCATIONNO, LOTNO, sum(INCOME-OUTGO) as STOCK
from LOCATION_DETAIL
where ITEMNO = 'AAA'
group by ITEMNO, LOCATIONNO, LOTNO
having sum(INCOME-OUTGO) > 0
order by LOTNO
fetch first row only
```

See also this dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/ve3WZ73u